# Change label text, text color, text size according to tableView results

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I have this code, where I have 2 Json arrays which I try to compare in my code -> all and allUrl. When array all contains some id from array allUrl image table row should be change to red, or vice versa green.

According this results I want to change label text, label text color, label text font size, but when I run app, label text still "PASSED" and gray, thanks.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let listOfStudentsUrl = allUrl.reduce(into: [String:String]()){$0[$1.id] =  $1.timestampValue} 
    // Compare data

    listOfStudentsUrl.forEach { key in print(key)    

        if all[indexPath.row].id == key.key {
            cell.textLabel?.text = all[indexPath.row].id
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = all[indexPath.row].timestampValue
            cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"red_icon")
            cell.isHidden = false
            statusLabel.text = "NOT PASSED"
            statusLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            statusLabel.font = statusLabel.font.withSize(35)
            break
        } else {
            statusLabel.text = "PASSED"
            statusLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
            statusLabel.font = statusLabel.font.withSize(35)
            cell.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    var rowHeight:CGFloat = 0.0
    let listOfStudentsUrl = allUrl.reduce(into: [String:String]()){$0[$1.id] =  $1.timestampValue}

    for key in listOfStudentsUrl{
        if all[indexPath.row].id == key.key {
            rowHeight = 49.0
            break
        } else {
            rowHeight = 0.0
        }
    }
    return rowHeight
}
```

Json format:

```
{
    "class": {
        "studentOne": {
            "stringValue": "2020-02-04"
        },
        "studentTwo ": {
            "stringValue": "2020-02-05"
        }
    },
    "createTime": "2020-03-30",
    "updateTime": "2020-03-30"
}
```

Comment: Hello, could you provide more informations about your Json all and allUrls ?

Comment: Hi Etienne, I added it into question.